# Почему RedCloth выводит сообщение, не форматируя его?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Использую **RedCloth** для форматирования текста. Но в результате он выводит моё сообщение, окружив его HTML-тегами, но не форматируя его. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я должен добавить в код?

*Вьюха - Show.rhtml*

```
<%= format(@post.content) %>
```

*Хэлпер - post_helper.rb*

```
def format(string)
    RedCloth.new(params[:string]).to_html
end
```

**Добавление - пример вывода.**

```
Content: <h1>Тестовый заголовок</h1><ul><li>Первый пункт меню</li> <li>Второй пункт меню</li> </ul>
```

В HTML выглядит так:

```
<p>     
    <b>Content:</b> 
    &lth1&gtТестовый пост&lt/h1&gt
    &ltul&gt
        &ltli&gtПервый пункт меню&lt/li&gt
        &ltli&gtВторой пункт меню&lt/li&gt
    &lt/ul&gt
</p>
```

Comment: А пример вывода можно?

Comment: Конечно:<br>

    Content: < h1 >Тестовый заголовок</ h1 > < ul > < li >Первый пункт меню</ li > < li >Второй пункт меню</ li > </ ul >

<br>

<br>

В исходном коде страницы написано так:<br>
    < p >     <br>
        < b >Content:</ b > <br>
        & lt;h1& gt;Тестовый пост&lt;/h1& gt;<br>
        & lt;ul& gt;<br>
         & lt;li& gt;Первый пункт меню&lt;/li& gt;<br>
         & lt;li& gt;Второй пункт меню&lt;/li& gt;<br>
        & lt;/ul& gt;<br>
    </ p >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решило проблему:

```
<%= format(@post.content).html_safe %>
```

Думаю что есть лучшие решения

Answer (score 1):

helper вообще использовать не надо, просто пишите в show `<%= raw RedCloth.new(@post.content).to_html %>`